# Best approach on handling function that returns either a promise or just synchronous code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I wrote some code and I'm trying to get some feedback on it. I'll try to summerize the essential only. I have a function that based on a condition returns a promise or something else:

```
this.isActive = function(){
  if(this.disableApplePay && window.ApplePaySession){
    return window.ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard(this.merchantId).then(function(response){
      return response;
    });
  }
  return !!(window.ApplePaySession && window.ApplePaySession.canMakePayments() &&
    window.ApplePaySession.supportsVersion(3));
}
```

Then I call this function to check `isActive()` in another few methods like this:

```
Promise.resolve(this.isActive()).then(function(response){
  if(response){
    //execute code here
  }
});
```

Is the `Promise.resolve()` in this case following best practice? Is there a better way to deal with the `isActive()` function?

PS: Let's exclude the async await for the sake of the above example please.

Comment: Please let me know the reason at least when you downvote so I can improve my question if needed.

Comment: You can find out yourself when you go to the [help] and read _How to ask a good question_. I am not happy with your hypothetical stub code, that's why I downvoted.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , but that is like how my code looks like(~99%), I read here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask about hypothetical code, but I don't know what to do to improve my question code. Should I post the whole real variables and functions? How would that help?

Comment: Post real and working code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , I updated the question. I hope it's ok now.

Comment: One of the problems with this question is that the question doesn't tell us what the code is doing, nor can we figure it out from the code itself.

Comment: This is not a reasonable requirement however almost as a hack, you may check if the returned value has a `then` method to decide what you will do next... Highly discouraged though. Please don't do such things.

Comment: "Let's exclude the async await" Nonononono, no exclusions please. Either you post the real code or you risk missing out. Please keep that in mind for your next question.

Comment: "I'll try to summerize the essential only."  On Stack Overflow, that's perfect. On Code Review, [we do things differently](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915). Please keep that in mind on your next question.

Answer (score 4):

You really don't want a function sometimes returning a promise and sometimes returning a value.  That just makes it difficult for the caller.  Instead, if you sometimes have a promise to return, then you should always return a promise.

```
function isActive(){
  if(condition){
    return API.someFunction().then(function(response){
      return response;
    });
  }
  return Promise.resolve(active);
}
```

Then, your caller can just know that it always returns a promise and they can code accordingly.  When you have complexity like this, it's better to encapsulate it in the function itself rather than make every single caller deal with it.

So, the caller can then always and consistently just do:

```
isActive().then(...).catch(...);
```

---

Also, if you actually have this in your real code:

```
   .then(function(response){
      return response;
    });
```

then, you can remove that entirely and just use this as it generates the exact same result, but is less code:

```
function isActive(){
  if(condition){
    return API.someFunction();
  }
  return Promise.resolve(active);
}
```

Both examples return a promise that resolves to `response`.  One is obviously a lot simpler than the other.

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Yes, as shown that's superfluous, but I assumed it was a placeholder for some actual code that does something with the response before returning a modified value.  I will add a comment to that effect.